# Marginal Distribution Function of Bernoulli #homework

Tags: probability

I am looking for a marginal distribution function for the following situation:
B is a random variable which represents the sum of D independent Bernoulli trials. The probability for success equals p. The amount of Bernoulli trials is a random variable (D), which behaves like a Poisson distribution function with parameter λ.

I have got a solution, but I am not sure if mine is correct.

d=0,1,2,3,4,5,6......

I could not upload the picture of my calculation so here is a link

[Calculation](http://s11.postimg.org/7i4kbpmhv/Screenshot_39.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: $b_i$ is never defined in your calculation, nor is the quantity $d$.  That is, I see a left-hand-side $Pr[B=b]$ (which has no $b_i$ or $d$) and a right-hand-side that has those things, so it makes no sense.  Your left-hand-side cannot possibly be the same as your right-hand-side.

Comment: I think what you mean is $Pr[B=b] = \sum_{d=0}^{\infty}Pr[B=b|D=d]Pr[D=d]$, which is the "law of total probability."

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to change this. bi=0+1i and d=number of bernoulli trials

Comment: And I would like to know a function, which calculates the marginal probability of any B given any D

Comment: This was not a simple matter of giving a definition.  Your calculation does not make sense.  You need to start over, perhaps using my above equation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equation that holds for all integers $b$: 
$$ \underbrace{Pr[B=b]}_{\mbox{left-hand-side}} = \underbrace{\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} Pr[B=b|D=d]Pr[D=d]}_{\mbox{right-hand-side}} $$

Structural observations of this equation:

- The left-hand-side depends on a parameter $b$, and nothing else.
- The right-hand-side depends on a parameter $b$, and nothing else. While the right-hand-side also has a variable $d$, this is a "dummy variable" that is summed out, so that the overall value of the right-hand-side is only affected by the parameter $b$ (its value can change as different values of $b$ are plugged in).

---

Derivation of the equation:  Recall the law of total probability that for any event $\mathcal{A}$ and any collection of "mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive" events $\{\mathcal{B}_0, \mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_2, ...\}$ we have: 
$$ Pr[\mathcal{A}] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} Pr[\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{B}_i]Pr[\mathcal{B}_i] $$

In this case you can define the events $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}_i$ by:

- $\mathcal{A} \equiv \{B=b\}$
- $\mathcal{B}_i \equiv \{D=i\}$ for $i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$. Note that these are indeed "mutually exclusive and collectively exhuastive."

---

Where to go from here:  Once you agree on the above equation, it remains only to compute:

- $Pr[D=d]$ for all relevant values of $d$ (of course, this is given to you: You are told that $D$ has a Poisson distribution)
- $Pr[B=b|D=d]$ (you must compute this for all relevant $b$ and $d$ values)

The conditional probabilities are indirectly given to you, since you are told that, given $D=d$, $B$ is the sum of $d$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables, and hence is a "famous" random variable (one that has a "name"). (Hint:  It is not "Gaussian" or "Bernoulli" but...).

Also notice that $Pr[B=23|D=4] = 0$, for obvious reasons, so you can restrict the summation to relevant terms.